# Most authentic Sichuanese food in Bristol (UK)?

Tags: food-and-drink

Heading to Bristol, UK for the day. Wondering where the most authentic Sichuanese food is in the city?

Looking online there seem to be a bunch of different options:

- Wong's Chinese
- Chilli Daddy
- Great Chongqing

It is hard to tell from online posts alone which would be the most authentic.

Ideas?

Comment: How can this be anything other than asking for opinion? I voted to close.